# Join 2 tables, sum and group by

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sum

Should be fairly simple but I am new to SQL and can't get it to work :

```
Table 1:
ID        Qty
ItemA     3 
ItemB     5  
ItemD     2 

Table 2:
ID        Qty
ItemC    -1
ItemB    1.5 
ItemE     2.2
```

I just  want one table with the Quantities summed by ID.

Comment: Can you clarify what your columns are? It's not too clear with the current markup.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, and your desired output?

Comment: “Table 1” and “Table 2” are really not useful names for tables. Why do you have two tables that apparently represent the exact same kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Qty) SumQty
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Qty FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Qty FROM Table2
) A
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Forgot to add "group by id"

Answer (score 0):

This will sum the `Qty` fields and group by ID:

```
SELECT
    a.ID AS id,
    (SUM(a.Qty) + SUM(b.Qty)) as qty_sum
FROM
    [Table 1] as a
        JOIN
    [Table 2] as b ON (a.ID = b.ID)
GROUP BY 1;
```

The key parts that you should take from this example are:

1. `JOIN` This is how you're two tables are connected. Note that it's making sure that the IDs match in both tables via the `ON (a.ID = b.ID)
2. Using the `SUM` function get your totals.
3. `GROUP BY` groups...

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @patsweet but use INNER JOIN and the formatting is easier to read

```
SELECT  SUM(t1.Qty + t1.Qty) AS TotalQty ,
        t1.ID
FROM    [Table 1] t1
        INNER JOIN [Table 2] t2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON t2.ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID
```